I am having an issue with phone number formatting in python
I am trying to format fake data from the Faker API. I am using pandas to store it into a data frame. I have figured out how to strip and replace any errors like no spacing, improper spacing, removing parenthesis, country code, and extensions. The main issue I am having is when numbers are coming out like this: xxxxxx-xxxx instead of like xxx-xxx-xxxx.
This is my code:
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd

fake = Faker()
name = []
address = []
number = []
ssn = []

for i in range(100):
    name.append(fake.name())
    address.append(fake.address().replace('\n', " "))
    ssn.append(fake.ssn())
    phone_number = fake.phone_number().split('x')[0].replace('.',"-").replace("(",'').replace(')','').replace(' ','')
    # How do to deal with the opposite of ^
    if phone_number.startswith('+1'):
        phone_number = phone_number[2:]
    if phone_number.startswith('1'):
        phone_number = phone_number[1:]
    if phone_number.startswith('001'):
        phone_number = phone_number[3:]
    
    phone_number = phone_number.lstrip('-')
    
    if phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 12: #10 or 12 work here for some reason, but I get diff. formats
        phone_number = f"{phone_number[:3]}-{phone_number[3:6]}-{phone_number[6:]}"
    else:
        phone_number = phone_number
    
    number.append(phone_number)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name, 'Address':address,'Phone Number':number, 'SSN':ssn})
df

Not too sure where my issue is.
I initially thought it was the length or if it was being read as an int instead of a string, but when I do this:
    if phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 12:
        phone_number = f"{phone_number[:3]}-{phone_number[3:6]}-{phone_number[6:]}"
    elif len(phone_number) != 12:
        phone_number = f"{phone_number[:3]}-{phone_number[3:6]}{phone_number[6:]}"
    else:
        phone_number = phone_number

it formats is like xxx-xxxxxxx.

If I do it this way:
    if phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 10:
        phone_number = f"{phone_number[:3]}-{phone_number[3:6]}-{phone_number[6:]}"
    elif len(phone_number) != 10:
        phone_number = f"{phone_number[:3]}-{phone_number[3:6]}{phone_number[6:]}"
    else:
        phone_number = phone_number

then the numbers are formatted like xxx--xxx-xxxx.

    if phone_number.isdigit() and len(phone_number) == 10:
        phone_number = f"{phone_number[:3]}-{phone_number[3:6]}-{phone_number[6:]}"
    else:
        phone_number = phone_number

And if I remove the elif then I get this output:'xxxxxx-xxxx'.

I am pretty much stuck and not sure what to do.

You need to use elif. Otherwise, each if condition is being applied to the result of the previous test.

@Barmar ok, I think its just a matter of length now. Like whether it is equal to 10 or 12

There's no need for else: phone_number = phone_number.

In this code:
    if phone_number.startswith('+1'):
        phone_number = phone_number[2:]
    if phone_number.startswith('1'):
        phone_number = phone_number[1:]
    if phone_number.startswith('001'):
        phone_number = phone_number[3:]

you're applying each test to the result of the previous assignment of phone_number. So if the phone number starts with +11, the first if block will remove +1, then the second test will succeed and remove the 1.
You should use elif so you're only testing the original number, not making incremental checks.
    if phone_number.startswith('+1'):
        phone_number = phone_number[2:]
    elif phone_number.startswith('1'):
        phone_number = phone_number[1:]
    elif phone_number.startswith('001'):
        phone_number = phone_number[3:]

Another option is to use a regular expression that removes any of these prefixes:
    phone_number = re.sub(r'^(\+1|1|001)', '', phone_number)

I haven't looked through the rest of your code, there may be more problems.

now the numbers are being formatted like 611492-0046 feel like im close. Maybe its the length im using in the if stmt after the phone_number = re.sub(r'^(\+1|1|001|-)', '', phone_number)

I don't see how you could be getting that from f"{phone_number[:3]}-{phone_number[3:6]}-{phone_number[6:]}" It clearly has three -.

if you print out the phone_numbers, youll see them in there

You should probably remove - from the input phone numbers.

that's all I needed to do. I just removed it from initial generation, then I formatted with the re.sub, then the length becomes 10. Then going through the if stmt, it becomes properly formatted. Thanks for your help!
